# Double Custom Backref-Text whilst Using natbib or natbibapa with apacite

Tags: hyperref, natbib, back-referencing, apacite

When I use natbibapa with apacite and insert backrefs, the custom text in the backref doubles as in this picture.

[image: MWE]

Any ideas, how to solve the problem?
Thanks!

Here’s a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref} 
%OR \usepackage{backref}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{Zitiert auf S.{\,}#1.}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{aaas1990,
 author = {{American Association for the Advancement of Science [AAAS]}},
 year = {1990},
 title = {{Science for all Americans}},
 address = {New York},
 publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
 key = {AAAS}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
I cite \citep{aaas1990}. %Problem occurs independent of the use of \cite{}, \citep{} or anything else.
\bibliography{jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\end{document}
```

- Problem occurs both with backref-option of hyperref or backref-package.
- Problem occurs both with natbibapa-option of apacite or natbib-package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{Zitiert auf S.{\,}#1.}` with `\renewcommand*{\backrefxxx}[3]{Zitiert auf S.{\,}#1.}`.

You can also add the following lines to the preamble to see that the command `backref` is called twice (I do not know why), but the first time round, its parameter is empty; the second time, the parameter contains the output of `\backrefxxx`:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{\textcolor{red}{BACKREF[1=#1]ENDOFBACKREF}}
\renewcommand*{\backrefxxx}[3]{\textcolor{blue}{XXX[1=#1][2=#2][3=#3]ENDOFXXX}}
```

[image: arguments of backref and backrefxxx]

A more elaborate replacement for `\backref` is called `\backrefalt`:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}   %% documentation says: use this when backref package version < 1.33
   %% I have 1.38 and when \backrefalt is defined, it replaces \backref
\renewcommand*{\backrefxxx}[3]{\textcolor{blue}{XXX[1=#1][2=#2][3=#3]ENDOFXXX}}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{\textcolor{green}{ALT[1=#1][2=#2][3=#3][4=#4]ENDOFALT}}
```

[image: arguments of backrefalt and backrefxxx]

Notice that the 1st and 3rd argument passed to `\backrefalt` are the number of citations (#1 is number of different backreferenced pages, #3 the total number of citations). Notice how with the following definition, nothing is output if #1=0 (the first call of `\backrefalt` above):

```
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \ifcase #1 {}%    %% do not output anything if the first argument is 0!!!
  \or     page #2%  %% first argument=1   => was cited on a single page
  \else   pages #2% %% first argument>1   => was cited on multiple pages
  \fi
}
```